# How to download PDF files in python that doesn't end with .pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, web, web-scraping

The URL looks like this: https://apps.websitename.com/AccountOnlineWeb/AccountOnlineCommand?command=getBlobImage&image=11/19/2019 I have tried everything. But none of them worked.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url ='https://apps.websitename.com/AccountOnlineWeb/AccountOnlineCommand?command=getBlobImage&image=11/19/2019'
s = requests.Session()
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))
with open('filepath/file.pdf', 'wb')as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

I tested getting a .jpg file from the website to make sure the authentication part is working. I have downloaded a file with a .pdf url that's not authenticated to make sure downloading pdf is working. But I just cannot download this file. 
I used `r.is_redirect` to test if the url redirects to another url for the PDF but it returned `False`
I should mention that when you open the file manually it just waits for like 2s and loads the PDF like a regular PDF and you can download it just like a regular PDF. 
Currently my code downloads a file that's supposed to be the PDF but it has 0 KB.

Comment: URL doesn't work

Comment: i know its an example. It says website.com.

Comment: yes once you log in to the website and click on this url it would take you to a pdf file. I used r.is_redirect to test if it redirects to a .pdf url at the end but it doesnt.

Comment: page may use JavaScript for this but request can't run JavaScript. You may have to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which runs JavaScript. OR you may try to use `DevTools` in `Chrome/Firefox`  to find (manually) url used by JavaScript and then use this url with `requests`. Later you my try to find this url in HTML or generate it using element from HTML.

Comment: I dont want to use selenium because I dont want to go click through the entire website and do all that manually. how would I find the hidden url to get to the PDF with dev tools? I tried googling but nothing useful came up. It would be great if you can refer me to a tutorial on this. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to give the actual url? Because it's hard to reproduce the issue without it.